# SQL using max date and grabbing unique type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to narrow down my results and need some input on how to do that.

What I'm trying to do is narrow this down so it's showing me the max maildate for each "Type". So in this case I want it showing me CatID MF on 2020-7-17 for Insert Sale and WK on 2018-08-31 for Core.

I was thinking maybe I need a case statement under my Where clause but I'm not sure how I would write that or if that's the best way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
SELECT 
pc.packnum
,pc.CatID 
,MAX(cc.firstreleasemailed) as Maildate
,v.Type 
FROM pic704current pc JOIN
     CatCov cc 
     ON pc.CatID = cc.Offer AND
        pc.Year = cc.MailYear CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (Case when cc.description like '%Promo%' then 'Promo' 
                   when cc.description like '%Sale%' then 'Insert Sale' 
                   when cc.Description like '%ins%' and cc.Description not like '%sale%' then 'Insert Core' 
                   when cc.description like '%ons%' then 'Onsert'
                   Else 'Core'
              end)
    ) v(type)
WHERE pc.DiscountReasonCode Not in ('LT','UP', 'OR', 'ER', 'IP', 'WT') 
AND
      cc.firstreleasemailed <= getdate() 
      And pc.PackNum = '6762846'
GROUP BY pc.packnum, pc.CatID, v.type
```

Current output:

```
PackNum  CatID  MailDate    Type
-------  -----  ----------  -----------
6762846  WA     2018-07-20  Core
6762846  WQ     2018-07-20  Core
6762846  MK     2019-02-15  Insert Sale
6762846  MF     2020-07-17  Insert Sale
6762846  MP     2020-03-27  Insert Sale
6762846  WK     2018-08-31  Core
6762846  LD     2020-07-10  Insert Sale
6762846  WM     2020-07-01  Insert Sale
6762846  LK     2019-01-04  Insert Sale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the `case` expression in the `group by`.  Or, as I like to do, use `apply`:

```
SELECT pc.packnum, pc.CatID, MAX(b.firstreleasemailed) as Maildate
       v.Type 
FROM pic704current pc JOIN
     CatCov cc 
     ON pc.CatID = cc.Offer AND
        pc.Year = cc.MailYear CROSS APPY
     (VALUES (Case when cc.description like '%Promo%' then 'Promo' 
                   when cc.description like '%Sale%' then 'Insert Sale' 
                   when cc.Description like '%ins%' and cc.Description not like '%sale%' then 'Insert Core' 
                   when cc.description like '%ons%' then 'Onsert'
                   Else 'Core'
              end)
    ) v(type)
WHERE pc.DiscountReasonCode Not in ('LT','UP', 'OR', 'ER', 'IP', 'WT') AND
      cc.firstreleasemailed <= getdate()
      pc.PackNum = '6762846'
GROUP BY pc.packnum, pc.CatID, v.type;
```

Note that I also changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names, so they make sense when reading the query.  Using *meaningful* table aliases is a best practice.

EDIT:

If you just want this for each type, then remove the other columns from the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT MAX(b.firstreleasemailed) as Maildate
       v.Type 
FROM pic704current pc JOIN
     CatCov cc 
     ON pc.CatID = cc.Offer AND
        pc.Year = cc.MailYear CROSS APPY
     (VALUES (Case when cc.description like '%Promo%' then 'Promo' 
                   when cc.description like '%Sale%' then 'Insert Sale' 
                   when cc.Description like '%ins%' and cc.Description not like '%sale%' then 'Insert Core' 
                   when cc.description like '%ons%' then 'Onsert'
                   Else 'Core'
              end)
    ) v(type)
WHERE pc.DiscountReasonCode Not in ('LT','UP', 'OR', 'ER', 'IP', 'WT') AND
      cc.firstreleasemailed <= getdate()
      pc.PackNum = '6762846'
GROUP BY v.type;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to give this a try. I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: I've updated my code but still getting the same output. I also appreciate the advice on the aliases. I am still learning SQL (self taught) and  I know I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: @Deke . . . If you want this for just `type`, then you should not have the other columns in the `group by` and `select`.

Comment: so I'd have to do a sub query to pull the packnum, and catid columns then?

Comment: @Deke . . . Those columns are not relevant to the question that you asked, which is about `type` and the minimum date for that.

Comment: True enough! Thanks for the help!!